# htaccess causing http 500 on file download

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, centos

I have CentOS Linux 7 running wordpress 4.2.3 with gravity forms plugin installed, in his new version too.

The plugin created an htaccess file in his upload folder with this directives:

```
# BEGIN Gravity Forms
# Disable parsing of PHP for some server configurations. This file may be removed or modified on certain server configurations by using by the gform_upload_root_htaccess_rules filter. Please consult your system administrator before removing this file.
<Files *>
    SetHandler none
    SetHandler default-handler
    Options -ExecCGI
    RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
</Files>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag engine off
</IfModule>
# END Gravity Forms
```

The problem when I try to download a file (image) in the folder it's an return http 500, if I change file name, everything is ok.

something in the htaccess doesn't work with server configuration ?

Comment: Can you show me the Apache error log that references this 500 error? It should be in /var/log/httpd/error_log, or something similar.

Comment: nothing get loged in the error_log but I found it another log -

httpd/domains/domain.com.log:745:172.17.41.5 - - [04/Aug/2015:11:46:39 + 0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-7457db24a52958f1b9d0d0b408d0ba37/ 2015/01/Desert.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 697 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) Ap pleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36"

Comment: That's the 500 error, doesn't seem very helpful. If you restart Apache does it  complain about the .htaccess file? Also, what do you mean when you say: "if I change file name, everything is ok." When you change the name of the image file?

Answer (score 1):

In short, add this to your Wordpress theme's functions.php (or any sane place of your choosing):

```
add_filter( 'gform_upload_root_htaccess_rules', '__return_false' );
```

This is a common issue with Gravity Forms on shared hosting. Gravity Forms added this .htaccess a year or so ago, as a response to an exploit in their plugin. This short-sighted (in my opinion) hack broke a lot of sites, so adding the above filter was their hack to fix to their hack.

You cannot just edit the .htaccess file until the site works. If you don't add this filter, Gravity Forms will recreate its original .htaccess file.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/security/#the-htaccess-file